# Search Container not Displaying

Tags: html, css

The small company I work for asked me to try to fix a search container on our website. The idea of it is that on clicking the small search icon, an input field fades in from the top. The way it is now, it fades in, then immediately disappears (and leaves a large bit of spacing on the header where it showed at (for a brief moment). Below is the HTML:

```js
.search - container {
    position: fixed;
    z - index: 99;
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 150 px;
    background: #77ab42; /*# 9e ba90;*/
    padding - top: 40 px;
    display: none;
  }
  .search - container input {
    -moz - border - radius: 5 px; -
    webkit - border - radius: 5 px;
    border - radius: 5 px; -
    webkit - appearance: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin - right: 2.3576515979 % ;
    width: 74.4105871005 % ;
    float: none;
    font - size: 16 px;
    font - size: 1.6 rem;
    height: 60 px;
    margin: 0 px auto!important;
    display: block;
    padding - left: 30 px;
    color: #4b4b4b;
font-weight: 100; }
.search-container input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <div class="search-box">X</div>
  <form method="get" class="animated fadeInDown" id="searchform" action="https://validityscreening.com/">
    <input type="text" size="put_a_size_here" name="s" id="s" value="Search 
the site..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
  </form>
</div>
```

From what I've observed in the DevTools, when the icon is clicked, around the time it disappears, the very first div is changing to the following:

```
<div class="search-container" style="display: none;">
```

Sorry for the wall of text; I appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make this effect? I'm not sure if this is what you want... take a look... Click on the X

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("s");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.search container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 150 px;
    background: #77ab42; /*# 9e ba90;*/
    padding - top: 40 px;
    display: none;
  }
  .search container input {
    -moz-border-radius: 5 px; -
    -webkit-border-radius: 5 px;
    border-radius: 5 px; -
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin - right: 2.3576515979 % ;
    width: 74.4105871005 % ;
    float: none;
    font - size: 16 px;
    font - size: 1.6 rem;
    height: 60 px;
    margin: 0 px auto!important;
    display: block;
    padding - left: 30 px;
    color: #4b4b4b;
font-weight: 100; }

.search-container input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <div class="search-box"  onclick="myFunction()">X</div>
  <form method="get" class="animated fadeInDown" id="searchform" action="https://validityscreening.com/">
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" size="put_a_size_here" name="s" id="s" value="Search 
the site..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's ultimately what I want it to do, but at the moment, the search box keeps disappearing. It will fade in, but then it immediately disappears.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. Something else must be jumping in there. I really appreciate your help! Gonna go ahead and mark it as the answer.

Comment: This does not fade in

Answer (score 0):

Couple notes:

- Use the `placeholder` attribute for default text
- `size="put_a_size_here"` is not valid

Here you go, hope this helps. This has the transition effect you are looking for I believe;

```js
document.querySelector('.search-box').onclick = () => {
  let form = document.querySelector('#searchform');
  if (form.classList.contains('fadeInDown')) {
    form.classList.remove('fadeInDown');
  } else {
    form.classList.add('fadeInDown');
  }
};
```

```css
.search-container {
  position: fixed;
  z - index: 99;
  width: 100 %;
  height: 150 px;
  background: #77ab42;
  /*# 9e ba90;*/
  padding - top: 40 px;
  //display: none;
}

.search-container input {
  -moz - border - radius: 5 px;
  - webkit - border - radius: 5 px;
  border - radius: 5 px;
  - webkit - appearance: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin - right: 2.3576515979 %;
  width: 74.4105871005 %;
  float: none;
  font - size: 16 px;
  font - size: 1.6 rem;
  height: 60 px;
  margin: 0 px auto!important;
  display: block;
  padding - left: 30 px;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.search-container input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.animated {
  height:0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.fadeInDown {
  visibility: visible;
  height:auto;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <div class="search-box">X</div>
  <form method="get" class="animated" id="searchform" action="https://validityscreening.com/">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search the site...">
  </form>
</div>
```